# Are there any temples of Vishnu or certain forms of Vishnu where he is worshipped with animal sacrifices?

Tags: vishnu, sacrifice, varaha, varaha-purana, meat

Recently, I came across the following reference from Varaha Purana (A Vaisnava Purana), where Varaharoopi Bhagavana Vishnu approves of animal sacrifice and meat offerings of certain kinds in his worship.

**[Varaha Purana Chapter 119](https://archive.org/details/toaz.info-varaha-purana-unabridged-motilal-englishpdf-pr_e1d9a18739bfe3dd54249588e67c9ece/page/276/mode/2up?view=theater)**

[image]

This was surprising for me, for I didn't Know certain Scriptures mention Animal Sacrifice for Forms of Lord Vishnu as well. Out of curiosity, I tried to make a search if there are any temples of Vishnu or forms of Vishnu where he is worshipped with animal sacrifices or meat offerings and the only temple matching the description I found until now is the [Ahobhilam Temple of Lord Narasimha](https://www.outlookindia.com/traveller/ot-getaway-guides/ahobilam-realm-man-lion/) where apparently Sri Narasimha is worshipped with animal sacrifices.

My Question is Are there are any other temples where Lord Vishnu or Any of the Forms of Lord Vishnu are currently worshipped with animal sacrifces? If not currently, were there any such temples in the past where such kind of worship of certain forms of Vishnu took place? Are there any historical records which prove worship of Vishnu or certain forms of vishnu with animal sacrifices took place during ancient times? An In-depth answer would be appreciated.

Comment: ONLY *ugra* form of the devta are prayed using Animal sacrifices. *Vishnu* and *Shiva* like forms are way too sattvik for it.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha  I understand, but From the Varaha purana verse  I think there may at least be some forms of Vishnu such as Shiva's Bhairava form which are or can be worshipped in that mode. Narasimha( at Ahobhilam temple) being an example. Would like to know if there are more examples like that

Comment: As far I'm aware - none. Puranas are *bhakti texts*! They don't have tantric practices such as *bali*. They rarely go beyond bhakti in some aspects. I'll doubt if they have any documentation of such practices that would have been done during those times. Although, there is some *panchamakara* associated with Vaishnavism, but not bali afi'ms.

Comment: @AbhasKumarSinha Tbh Puranas do mention Pashu bali, albeit it's mostly in Devi related puranas or in context of Shakti worship. The Varaha purana citation which I quoted in the question description is the first instance I have come across in puranas where such a thing is mentioned for Varaha (Vishnu)  and honestly I myself was surprised at it.

Comment: The do mention parallel practices and describe them at times. But they DON'T tell you the rituals, and mantras associated with it. That is something you have to learn from a personal guru and is less related to bhakti than puran.